# Compiling Kotlin Coroutines dependency for different target Linux architecture

Tags: cross-compiling, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native, archlinux-arm

I was working on a Kotlin Native/Multiplatform project intended for `linuxArm`, using `coroutines-core` (1.4.21) but using the `macosX64` target for development on my MacBook. I was devastated when I went to finally compile for `linuxArm64` that Gradle spit a bunch of errors that was, basically, `coroutines-core` does not have `linuxArmXX` variants.

I had previously compiled and ran a project **without coroutines** for the `linuxArm32` and `linuxArm64` targets and ran the binaries successfully on my RPi 3 (linuxArm).

Roman Elizarov himself states that one can compile for an alternate architecture on a host machine from sources: [Coroutines are not built for arm ( targets linuxArm32Hfp and others) #855](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/855)

How does one do this? I have a basic understanding of Gradle and I can `gcc` a command line “helloworld”, but compiling an entire KN dependency from sources? Seems like alchemy.

Answer (score 1):

## kotlinx.coroutines with linuxArm64 and linuxArm32Hfp

This fork has minimal changes to allow building linuxArm64 and linuxArm32Hfp kotlin native libraries.

Binaries are available on my maven repository at:
`https://h1.danbrough.org/maven`

The current versions available are:

- 1.5.2-danbroid
- 1.5.2-danbroid-native-mt
- 1.6.0-RC-danbroid

With the source code at:
https://github.com/danbrough/kotlinx.coroutines
and https://github.com/danbrough/kotlinx.atomicfu